# ActionMailer::Base.mail method is 'Not available' when called from initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'd like to create a handler that rescues emails (mostly from timeout errors), so I can try to resend them later.
Others suggested that an initializer with ActionMailer::DeliveryJob.rescue_from defined in it would do (we use deliver_later, cannot rescue that). Also, I need to render the email as our templates refer to activerecord models, hence change might happen if I render the emails right before sending them again.
My issue is that ActionMailer::Base.mail seems to be unavailable here:

```
ActionMailer::DeliveryJob.rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
    attempt = EmailAttempt.new
    attempt.error_class    = exception.class.to_s
    attempt.mailer         = self.arguments[0]
    attempt.email_template = self.arguments[1]
    attempt.params         = self.arguments[3]
    attempt.enqueued_at    = self.enqueued_at
    attempt.timezone       = self.timezone

    attempt.email_body = ActionMailer::Base.mail(**self.arguments[3][:email]) do |format|
      format.html do
          render locals: self.arguments[3][:body]
      end
    end

    attempt.save!
end
```

Stopping the code before calling the mail method, and just putting `ActionMailer::Base.mail` in debug console yield a 'Not available' message (the class seems to be available, ActionMailer::Base.methods will print a lot of stuff, `mail` is not among them).

Please ignore the parametrization of the method, it is a very much in progress code, but I can sort out (I think) what parameters to feed it with, once I figure out how to call it.

I am definitely not knee deep into Ruby or Rails, so this might be rookie mistake, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It seems its something with the debugger, the method is there if I use byebug instead.

Before, I used the built in VS Code debugger (with ruby-debug-ide and debase gems), but it seems it works slightly differently than byebug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).